# Logging python to pm2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pm2

I've got a Python script, started using pm2.

Is it possible to get realtime logs without stopping the Python script via pm2?

```
import zerorpc
import logging

class MyServer(object):

        def call(self):
                logging.info('hello : info')
                logging.warn('hello : warn')
                logging.error('hello : error')
                print('hello : print')
                return 'Hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
        s = zerorpc.Server(MyServer())
        s.bind('tcp://0.0.0.0:4243')
        s.run()
        print('hello: right after run')
```

This is a sample code for testing purposes, it uses zerorpc as a server, but I get the same behavior with flask with its integrated webserver.

Start this script from the command line with this command:

```
zerorpc --client --connect tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 call
```

This will write to output:

```
WARNING:root:hello : warn
ERROR:root:hello : error
hello : print
```

But starting this with pm2 will output:

```
zero_rpc_server-7 WARNING:root:hello : warn
zero_rpc_server-7 ERROR:root:hello : error
```

We lost the print, and all goes to error pm2 logs.
Any idea to log to pm2 out logs?

Comment: A code snippet would gather more readers, and therefore more answers.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Edited the question for more information

Comment: Found the answer in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959217/pm2-doesnt-log-python3-print-statements